# c++ ifstream cant read string, and getting error when read char

Tags: c++, ifstream

I have this code that writes to a file:

```
cout << "titre = ";
cin >> livre.titre;
cout << "isbn = ";
cin >> livre.isbn;
cout << "auteur = ";
cin >> livre.auteur;
cout << "annee = ";
cin >> livre.annee;
cout << "editeur = ";
cin >> livre.editeur;
cout << "prix = ";
cin >> livre.prix;
cout<<"===================="<<endl;

ofstream write("livres",ios::app);
write.write (( char *)&livre, sizeof livre );
write.close ();}
```

and this one to read from the file:

```
 void affiche ()
 {
    livres livre;
    ifstream read ("livres");
    read.read (( char *)&livre,sizeof livre);
    while (read)
    {
        cout << "num : " << livre.num
             << "  | isbn : " << livre.isbn
             << "  | titre : " << livre.titre
             << "  | auteur : " << livre.auteur
             << "  | editeur : " << livre.editeur
             << "  | annee : " << livre.annee
             << "  | prix : " << livre.prix
             << endl;
        read.read (( char *)&livre, sizeof livre);
    }
    read.close ();
}
```

Now, if I define the variables as `char` as in:

```
char titre[3];
char auteur[3];
char editeur[3];
```

The first `cout` would output all the 3 chars. For example, if I fill `titre` with `'abc'` and `auteur` with `'def'` and `editeur` with `'ghi'`; the output I get from cout for `titre` is `abcdefghi`, the output from cout for `auteur` is `defghi`, and the output for `editeur` is `ghi`. The problem doesn't occur if I define my three variables as `int`s. And when I change these variables to string, the compiler works well, but the exe sticks in the first string cout.

Here's the full code:

```
class livres{
public:
void creer () {
    cout << "titre = ";
    cin >> livre.titre;
    cout << "isbn = ";
    cin >> livre.isbn;
    cout << "auteur = ";
    cin >> livre.auteur;
    cout << "annee = ";
    cin >> livre.annee;
    cout << "editeur = ";
    cin >> livre.editeur;
    cout << "prix = ";
    cin >> livre.prix;
    ofstream write("livres",ios::app);
    write.write (( char *)&livre, sizeof livre );
    write.close ();}
 void affiche ()
 {
    livres livre;
    ifstream read ("livres");
    read.read (( char *)&livre,sizeof livre);
    while (read)
    {
        cout << "num : " << livre.num
             << "  | isbn : " << livre.isbn
             << "  | titre : " << livre.titre
             << "  | auteur : " << livre.auteur
             << "  | editeur : " << livre.editeur
             << "  | annee : " << livre.annee
             << "  | prix : " << livre.prix
             << endl;
        read.read (( char *)&livre, sizeof livre);
    }
    read.close ();
}

private:
    int isbn;
    char titre[3];
    char auteur[3];
    char editeur[3];
    int annee;
    int prix;
    int num;
};

int main()
{
    livres livre;
    livre.creer();
    livre.affiche();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char titre[3];` is only big enough to store _two_ printable characters.

Comment: The class `livres` doesn't have any variable called `livre`, so you should be getting compilation errors. You're also potentially writing garbage to the `livres` file as `&livre` will give you an address of the variable `livre`.

Comment: livre is an object in class livres, and i get no compilation error, the code works well without chars (with just integers, and with one char).

Comment: in `libres::creer()` you should use `cin >> this->titre`, etc instead of livre.titre. frankly I don't even know how livre.titre would be accessed since there is no variable in the function that has that name, only a local variable in `livres::affiche()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your character array lacks a null character '\0' at the end of it, which causes the program to read past the end of your intended string.  The null character is used to mark the end of a string, so any string of length 3 requires an array of length 4 so there is space for the null string at the end.  More info here: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/ntcs/

You are seeing "abcdefghi" because your three character arrays are stored in contiguous memory.  Since there is no '\0' character, the program reads past your first array and finds the next two.

How are you assigning characters to your arrays?  If you initialized them like this:

```
    char titre[3] = "abc";
```

You should see a compile error

```
    error: initializer-string for array of chars is too long [-fpermissive] 
    char titre[3] = "abc";
```

The compiler knows "abc" is too long because it needs that 4th space for a null character.

Comment: @ARDV  It would be nice of you to Accept the answer that caweeks provided.